# SQL select all values from table where all columns filled with data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

If I have table like this:

[image]

I need to return all values that are fully filled with data inside each row. If it has a blank value inside one row, then it shouldn't return that row.
Here is an example of an expected outcome:

[image]

also how would I have the code to combine with inner join statement.

Comment: Do you mean null when you say "blank"?

Comment: Look at SELECT * FROM Table WHERE columnA<>'' AND columnB<>'' etc... Even declare the 'Test' as a variable to be even neater. But basically have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: @indofraiser, a table has _columns_, not _fields_. (A timestamp has _fields_ for hours, minutes etc.)

Comment: Yeap, was just editing, post lunch brain fade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to just check each column:

```
SELECT ID, A, B, C, D
FROM yourTable
WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL AND D IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "blank," whether that means a `NULL` value or possible empty string.  Here is a version which covers both possibilities:

```
SELECT ID, A, B, C, D
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    COALESCE(A, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(B, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(C, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(D, '') <> '';
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two methods.  If the values are `NULL`, then as Tim points out, you can do:

```
WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL AND D IS NOT NULL
```

If "empty" might mean empty strings, then the simplest method is:

```
WHERE A > '' AND B > '' AND C > '' AND D > ''
```

Note:  This will may not work for numeric values.  But in that case, you want the direct comparison to `NULL`.

Comment: Im having an error message ERROR CODE: 1222 The used select staments have a difererent number of columns for the following code `select *
from outerbarcodes
where not exists (select 1
                  from bridgebarcodes
                  where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode
                 )
                 union
 SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode
FROM outerbarcodes
WHERE
    COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(size, '') <> ''`

Comment: @Eduards . . . And what does the code in your comment have to do with this answer?  The answer that you accepted has `COALESCE()`, for instance, this answer does not.

Comment: I can extract all values that are not null and give me the results that I need. Secondly, I need to show all values that do not match between two tables. But the second table only has two columns

Comment: @Eduards . . . This has nothing to do with the question you asked or with this answer.

Comment: Its an in depth question, im just a beginner to this